# How to do Right to Left Layout and text change for arabic Translation with Google Translator

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I have change the webpage should display form Right to left for arabic and Left to write for English with Layout Change.

When I have  use Google translate it will replace the Content in the same place with particular Language.

For arabic the letter should start from Rightto left, How could do that.

AnyPlugins for Javascript without change the markup.

help will be appreciated.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Google Translation</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="google_translate_element" style="display: none">
    </div>
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, multilanguagePage: true, autoDisplay: false }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

 <div style="border:0px dotted #ccc;padding:3px 3px 3px 0px;background-color:none;margin:7px 0 7px 0;">






</div>

    <h1> Site Is  Down ,Under Development Reach you soon</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

problem See the Screencast
Demo:http://recordit.co/TsVwSYJDxk

I need the output like this:

Demo: http://recordit.co/4TcwtDPQQf

Comment: If you can detect when the text is arabic you could set the element's direction to rtl. For example, this style will make the `h1` element display from right to left: `h1 {direction: rtl;}`

Comment: If I am making h1 as RTL it will be apply for all languages as English,Arabic etc,in my case when I choose Arabic it should start from RTL where I have check the condition,I don't want English,Spanish start from right to left.see the screencast above

Answer (score 4):

Try this. What it does is detect when the dropdown changes, get the language it changed to, and then modify the style of the text to be left to right or right to left depending on the language selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Translation</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
          new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, multilanguagePage: true, autoDisplay: false }, 'google_translate_element');
            $('.goog-te-menu-value').on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'span', function(){
                   language = $(".goog-te-menu-value span").html();

                    if (language == "Arabic"){
                        $('#theContent').css('direction', 'rtl');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#theContent').css('direction', 'ltr');
                    };
                });
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="theContent">
        <div id="google_translate_element" ></div>
        <div style="border:0px dotted #ccc;padding:3px 3px 3px 0px;background-color:none;margin:7px 0 7px 0;"></div>
        <h1> Site Is  Down ,Under Development Reach you soon</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```